# Does "crashing" sound appropriate in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning

> He was walking down a corridor of glass offices when a masked man came
> crashing through the glass from inside one of the offices and shoved
> him through the glass wall on the other side.

Can "crashing" be used here if the masked man was running or jumping through the glass deliberately to attack the other man without falling in the process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be the word I would use to describe the action of jumping through glass to attack. See the second definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crash). The use of "smashing" would also be valid but not as idiomatic, it doesn't fully encompass the context of jumping through the glass to attack.